# GPU computation fails with Keras (Anaconda) - Possibly insufficient driver version: 390.87.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I've installed `tensorflow-gpu` with Anaconda (5.3.0, python 3.6), however when I tried to run a script, the model starts, I can see that all GPUs become active, **but after a second**, they all drop to zero and the kernel hangs.

Also,  I've got the following errors:

```
2019-01-17 22:15:59.437729: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:353] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2019-01-17 22:15:59.437826: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:361] Possibly insufficient driver version: 390.87.0
[I 22:16:02.376 LabApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
```

My system information:

Ubuntu 18.04.1 LST
Anaconda (5.3.0) with the virtual env. Python version 3.6.6 and tensorflow installed through: `conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu`

My **GPU**s:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep cudnn
ii  libcudnn7                                  7.1.4.18-1+cuda9.0                           amd64        cuDNN runtime libraries
ii  libcudnn7-dev                              7.1.4.18-1+cuda9.0                           amd64        cuDNN development libraries and headers
ii  libcudnn7-doc                              7.1.4.18-1+cuda9.0                           amd64        cuDNN documents and samples


+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.87                 Driver Version: 390.87                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:04:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 29%   24C    P8    14W / 250W |      2MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:06:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 29%   25C    P8    15W / 250W |      2MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:07:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 25%   22C    P8    16W / 250W |      2MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:08:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 29%   26C    P8    14W / 250W |      2MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   4  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:0B:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 23%   31C    P8    15W / 250W |      2MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   5  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:0C:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 23%   27C    P8    15W / 250W |      2MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   6  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:0D:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 23%   24C    P8    15W / 250W |      2MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   7  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:0E:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 23%   28C    P8    16W / 250W |      2MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   8  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:0F:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 23%   24C    P8    15W / 250W |      2MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   9  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:82:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 23%   25C    P8    16W / 250W |      2MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And the command line output (I'm using jupyter lab)

```
2019-01-17 22:15:55.042286: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1490] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
2019-01-17 22:15:57.568878: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-01-17 22:15:57.568932: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:977]      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
2019-01-17 22:15:57.568938: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990] 0:   N Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y N
2019-01-17 22:15:57.568943: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990] 1:   Y N Y Y Y Y Y Y Y N
2019-01-17 22:15:57.568946: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990] 2:   Y Y N Y Y Y Y Y Y N
2019-01-17 22:15:57.568950: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990] 3:   Y Y Y N Y Y Y Y Y N
2019-01-17 22:15:57.568954: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990] 4:   Y Y Y Y N Y Y Y Y N
2019-01-17 22:15:57.568958: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990] 5:   Y Y Y Y Y N Y Y Y N
2019-01-17 22:15:57.568963: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990] 6:   Y Y Y Y Y Y N Y Y N
2019-01-17 22:15:57.568982: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990] 7:   Y Y Y Y Y Y Y N Y N
2019-01-17 22:15:57.568986: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990] 8:   Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y N N
2019-01-17 22:15:57.568995: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990] 9:   N N N N N N N N N N
2019-01-17 22:15:57.571075: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1103] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 10401 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:04:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2019-01-17 22:15:57.715851: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1103] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 10401 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 1, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:06:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2019-01-17 22:15:57.859939: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1103] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:2 with 10401 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 2, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:07:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2019-01-17 22:15:58.003691: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1103] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:3 with 10401 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 3, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:08:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2019-01-17 22:15:58.147301: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1103] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:4 with 10401 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 4, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:0b:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2019-01-17 22:15:58.290928: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1103] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:5 with 10401 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 5, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:0c:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2019-01-17 22:15:58.434501: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1103] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:6 with 10401 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 6, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:0d:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2019-01-17 22:15:58.578104: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1103] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:7 with 10401 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 7, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:0e:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2019-01-17 22:15:58.721778: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1103] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:8 with 10401 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 8, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:0f:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2019-01-17 22:15:58.865741: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1103] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:9 with 10401 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 9, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:82:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2019-01-17 22:15:59.437729: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:353] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2019-01-17 22:15:59.437826: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:361] Possibly insufficient driver version: 390.87.0
```

I'm trying to search on internet this problem and there are a lot of confusing solutions. Please help!

Comment: I had a similar thing few weeks ago. I was also using Jyputer Lab and tf /tf-gpu from Anaconda on Ubuntu 16.04 and sometimes the kernel got stuck without even responding to interrupts or restarts (only shutdown and start again). I moved to the pip-installed version of tf/jupyter and the problem got solved. I hope this helps.

Comment: @Vlad, thanks! Have you `pip install tensorflow-gpu` within the conda env?

Comment: No, just regular pip.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error with redhat7.9, tf2.3, nvidia430.40, cuda10.1. But it was solved when I install torch==1.2 and import torch before tensorflow. And it failed again when I update torch to 1.6

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30178706)